# Android: Centering multiple imageViews in LinearLayout with enough margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not a seasoned android developer so excuse my uninformedness. I am supposed to have 2 image views side by side horizontally, both of them centered appropriately such that there is enough margin like the following example:

```
----------------------------------- 
|                                 |
|          A          B           |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

I am using a linearLayout and using the centre alignment and I am getting this:

```
----------------------------------- 
|                                 |
|               AB                |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to avoid padding because I may have to dynamically add more elements which should then centre themselves again with enough margins. Please suggest if it can be done in a linearLayout or otherwise suggest another layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **weight** in LinearLayout because it's divide into 2 parts.

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:oriantion="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, is it necessary to add weightSum at all? Because if I add more elements, I would need to change the weightSum. I think if I do not specify it all, it will be automatically calculated right?

Comment: yes if you add one more image then weightsum =  3 in linearlayout and imageview weight=1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Just replace your image in the **src**. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Actually I want to avoid hardcoding for just 2 elements. I may add more imageViews programmatically and would prefer the layout to adjust on its own. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @EkanshGupta is there any limit on number on images?

Comment: Yes, 5 I'd say.

Comment: @EkanshGupta If you know maximum number of images (i.e 5) than you can add five ImageViews as mentioned in answer and than set the Visiblity (Visible / Gone) of imageviews depending upon how many you want to add.

Comment: Interesting. Also, would setting the visibility to visible/invisible be faster than the traditional delete/add imageviews in the layout?

Comment: @EkanshGupta Yes indeed cause images already been loaded in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Thats when layout_weight come to action this is a way of arranging items in a linear layout and saying how much space each view will take. So for a single linear layout all childrens total weight will dictate how much percentage each view will take if layout weight of first image is 1 and the other also 1. Then for this layout the total will be 2. So the first image will take (1/2)half and so is the other. You can also change layout weight programmatically for xml its like!

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is an optional attribute weightsum in the linear layout but the system will calculate it anyway. For this example will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Define a LinearLayout in your layout file with horizontal orientation (to add Views as columns, and not as rows) and horizontal gravity (this aligns to the center the ImageViews you want to add):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/servicesLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your code, obtain your LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout yourLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
```

Define a common LayoutParams object:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
```

And add your ImageViews to your LinearLayout with a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagesToAdd.size(); i++) {
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
    imgView.setImageResource("yourResourceID" + i);
    imgView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    yourLinearLayout.addView(imgView);
}
```

You'd need to do some extra work, if you add too many ImageViews, since they'll end up cropped.